# Can a function be written to check sql injection attacks

Tags: function, triggers, sql-injection

Can a function check for sql-injection ?  which can then  be called from an `insert trigger` ?

Comment: You're fixing the problem at far too low a level, and too late also. The fix is called parameters, and you use them between a client language and the database system. And an injection attempt may transform the insert but keep it completely benign, whilst doing bad things via a smuggled additional statement.

Comment: SQL injection happen when you mix together developer-provided code and user-provided data. In the final SQL code you can’t tell which is which. However, you don’t have to check for SQL injection if you use techniques which prevent them in the first place: if you keep code and data strictly separated, as provided by parameterized statements, the data won’t be mistakenly interpreted as code.